# PIL Bicubic Interpolation wi

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

So, I have an ndarray of the shape: `(28, 28, 1)` and I want to use bicubic interpolation to upscale it to `(33, 33, 1)`.
Here's what I got by searching online:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image as pil_image

...

img = np.array(pil_image.fromarray(img).resize(intermediate_dim, pil_image.BICUBIC))
# print(img.shape) -> (28, 28, 1), print(intermediate_dim) -> (33, 33)
```

But I keep getting an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "filters.py", line 256, in 
>           visualize_layer(mnist, LAYER_NAME)
>         File "filters.py", line 232, in visualize_layer
>           img_loss = _generate_filter_image(input_img, output_layer.output, f)
>         File "filters.py", line 161, in _generate_filter_image
>           img = np.array(pil_image.fromarray(img).resize(intermediate_dim, pil_image.BICUBIC))
>         File "BlaBlaBla\Python37\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2682, in fromarray
>           raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type: %s, %s" % typekey)
>       TypeError: Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 1), |u1

After seeing this, I tried using `img.astype(np.uint8)` but nothing helped. 
What am I doing wrong?

P.S. I am certain that the array contains legal values (integers from [0, 255])

Comment: Please show your code, including your `import` statements and how you loaded the image. Also, please show your image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell About the loading... That's a filter from a Keras CNN. I didn't want to involve machine learning stuff in my question, because it "shouldn't" matter, this is just a matrix of numbers that I want to use as grayscale values for an image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I can upload an original scale 28x28 version of the picture that I saved using `pyplot`, but it literally looks just like noise.

Comment: You probably need `np.squeeze()` because your array is (28,28,1) rather than (28,28).

Comment: Have you checked the `img.dtype()` is np.uint8?

Comment: @MarkSetchell type is correct, np.squeeze caused a different error: `Input to reshape is a tensor with 1089 values, but the requested shape has 784`. Note that 33^2=1089 and 28^2=784.

Comment: Try `pil_image.fromarray(img[...,0])` to remove that trailing dimension.

Comment: In case you are not familiar `img[...,0]` is a synonym for `img[:,:,0]` but it means I don't need to know the number of colons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array you are trying to create a PIL Image from is shaped:

```
(28,28,1)
```

and that is not a shape that PIL likes. It likes:

```
(M,N) for greyscale images
(M,N,3) for RGB images
(M,N,4) for RGBA images
```

So, you can use the following to select the first channel of that last unused dimension:

```
img = np.array(pil_image.fromarray(img[...,0]).resize(intermediate_dim, pil_image.BICUBIC))
```